# Definition of periodic conditions

Tags: regions, periodic-function

I want to define some periodic conditions, for example, describing an ellipse in 2D with periods $p_1$ in $x_1$ direction and $p_2$ in $x_2$ direction. I am frying my brain trying to implement this, but I don't see the obvious simple code. My attempt is to create a bunch of conditions with `Table` and use `Or`, as follows, but how would you do this correctly for the whole space?

```
x = {x1, x2};
c = {-1, -2};
a = {2, 1};
p = {5, 6};
conds = Or @@ Flatten@Table[
     Norm[DiagonalMatrix[1/a].(x - c - {p1, p2})] <= 1
     , {p1, -3*p[[1]], 3*p[[1]], p[[1]]}
     , {p2, -3*p[[2]], 3*p[[2]], p[[2]]}
     ];
RegionPlot[conds
 , {x1, -10, 10}
 , {x2, -10, 10}
 , Axes -> True
 , Epilog -> {
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, c}]
   , Red, Arrow[{c, c + {p[[1]], 0}}]
   , Blue, Arrow[{c, c + {0, p[[2]]}}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

EDIT: later, based on the defined periodic conditions, I want to define an implicit region and compute on it. But first, I want to understand, how to define correctly the describing conditions periodically.

Comment: If this is how to draw the periodic array then I would define one centered on {0,0} and then use `Translate` to draw the others. If you are trying to find the period from a diagram then I would use `Fourier`.

Comment: I am interested in the implementation of the mathematical definition, since later I want to define an implicit region an compute on it